# Design patterns for persisting Azure Blob storage lease IDs?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-for-java

Using Azure storage java SDK v12 and looking for best approach to persisting acquired leaseIds for leases on blobs.

Storing the leaseId in a blob tag? Blob metadata? Store in table? Storage queues for each user where I can push/pop leaseIds keyed to blob path?

Seems the easy and simple approach is to set it in a tag or even metadata for given blob. This would also mean additional controls around preventing anyone other than editor to make changes to the blob while it's leased.

Storing in a table seems like overkill and adds some complexity to the design.

We also considered using finite leases, and simply make async calls to renew for as long as a user is sitting on the edit screen in our web app, but this would cause many extra calls to azure storage (at least every 60 seconds, if we want to keep it leased)

Thoughts?

How are others implementing leases in azure storage sdk?